# iPhone returns to black screen after sleep interrupt during splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, splash-screen, interrupt-handling, default.png

I've got a strange bug going on that seems to be OS related : If I give a sleep interrupt to my device while the OS controlled splash screen, Default.png, is displayed, and then immediately wake the device, I get a black screen until `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is called and the OS passes control to my app.

It would be nice if upon waking the device, Default.png still displayed properly.  I put some logs in to see when the interrupt handlers (`applicationWillResignActive:` etc.) get called, but they never do - I think the interrupt is happening too soon.

Any ideas on how to avoid returning to a black screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any control over the splash screen how long it will display. The Default.png file will show while the app is being set up, but will disappear as soon as the app is ready to launch.

If you need more time to finish loading, you should create another view that looks like the splash screen that you have control over.

Just know that Apple is prickly when it comes to how the splash screen is used. They are of the opinion that your app shouldn't have one anyway. So be careful how long you sit on an empty/splash screen. Display a progress view or activity indicator to let the user know that you haven't crashed and are still working.

Comment: I think this is not what _Ian_ was asking about. Imagine, that you put `sleep(10);` before calling `UIApplicationMain()`. You will see splash screen. Then you interrupt your app. Then you awake and unlock the screen (`sleep(10);` has not returned yet). I checked it on iPod; indeed, there is no splash screen anymore...

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  The sleep/wake happens before the app is finished setting up.  I would expect the OS to see that the app is not done setting up and display the splash screen again, but it doesn't.  It just sits on a black screen until the app has finished setting up, then my app takes over and continues as it should.  What you're telling me is that this is 100% in the OS and I can't do anything about it, which I would believe.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The splash screen is only supposed to be a temporary placeholder while the app is setting up. If it doesn't look right, or not getting done quick enough... I would create a landing page to show the user that you are still loading up. Looks better than black screens. (and black screens could get you rejected when you submit to the App Store) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I'm doing that - my point is that if you give the device a sleep interrupt while the splash screen is showing, and then wake the device, you will get a black screen that you can do nothing about because the OS has not given control to your app yet.  Sounds like an OS issue to me.  If anyone reading has a work around, I'd love to hear it :)